# Drawing image file to SurfaceView returning blank

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, surfaceview

I want to draw an image file to a SurfaceView, but when I run my code, the SurfaceView is completely blank

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit);
    displayPicture();
}

private void displayPicture(){
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svEditPic);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    sv.draw(c);
}
```

This does not seem to work. Any solution?

Comment: Where do you place the above code? Please show more code.

Comment: Updated. It it placed within the onCreate method.

Comment: Set brakepoint on Canvas c = new Canvas(); and check if image is loaded.

Comment: CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivEdit);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
    c = new Canvas(temp);
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    iv.setImageBitmap(temp);
```

After some extensive searching, I found out that SurfaceView.draw(canvas) does not draw to itself. In fact, it does the opposite. It was drawing to the canvas. I've replaced the SurfaceView with and ImageView which will be more practical for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

If your drawing class extends View, you need to implement:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {}
```

and do your drawing stuff there.

Check BitmapDecode.java sample in your android sdk folder. Also, please read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

Comment: Surfaces are not fire-and-forget draw elements, you need to redraw them according to state every frame. Frame rate can be fixed, according to performance, or only when called. Follow @Melquiades advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this, 
 use some value for screen X, Y pos for `screenPts.x, screenPts.y` respectively

```
SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svEditPic);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y, null);
    bmp.recycle();
    sv.draw(c);
```

Comment: Still blank. if x and y are both 0 then it should print the picture at the top left, right? I shouldn't have to change the coordinates.

Comment: and use some different value for screenPts.x, screenPts.y

Comment: agree with @Melquiades advice.